# What is the meaning of mounting /dev/sda1 to /etc/hosts in Docker container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, docker

I run a simple docker container with `sudo docker run -it ubuntu:latest /bin/bash`

When I examine mounted file system, with: `df -h`, one

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          63G  4.3G   56G   8% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        63G  4.3G   56G   8% /etc/hosts
....
```

I fail to understand the last line, i.e. `/dev/sda1 -> /etc/hosts`, when I run `df -h` on the host machine, I get the mount `/dev/sda1 -> /`.

So `/dev/sda1` is actually my hard drive, why is it mounted to `/etc/hosts` on the container, and how come `/etc/hosts` on the container is a file with correct content.

Any explanation of what is going on here? how does this work?

EDIT: relevant output of findmnt:

```
`-/etc/hosts                    /dev/sda1[/lib/docker/containers/b18928987f05513ea9fcc9bd630e9efb0f92e51f48afd215426ba4cd83967fc1/hosts]
                                                                                                                     ext4    rw,relatime,data=ordered
```

Comment: Please show the output of `findmnt`, as df omits a lot of information.

Comment: @grawity please find edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux allows mounting (*binding*) the same filesystem at multiple paths, and it also allows binding an existing directory over another directory, or a file over another file.

This is used similar to symlinks but can cross container or chroot boundaries – if a file from the host has been bind-mounted onto a file inside a container, then the container can still access it.

*df* only shows the device because it reads mount information in the old "mtab" format, which doesn't have enough information about such things. (It still makes some sense with directory bind-mounts, though.)

Comment: Thx for the explanation